# How to Edit Custom (Server) Document Properties - Microsoft Word 2013 (VB Macros)

Tags: vba, ms-word

A Microsoft Word 2013 document at work has the Document Information Panel (DIP) displayed by default, with what is listed as "Document Properties - Server".

I'm trying to make a VB Macro that will involve editing these custom properties. However they don't seem to exist in ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties, or ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties. I know this because I ran through the list, displaying them one by one, as well as searching them by name.

The first property on the DIP called 'Title' showed up (in the latter list), but none of the other properties. It's worth noting that some are dropdowns, and one is a date with a calendar feature. I should also mention that I get a Run-time error near the end of the list of BuiltInDocumentProperties.

Is there another list where I can access these server properties, or some other issue that I'm overlooking? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find them. They are listed in ActiveDocument.ContentTypeProperties